# Total score for the facet in solr & sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, facet

After search each facet row has value and count of the hits.

Is it somehow possible to get total score (sum) of all hits in the facet without firing new searches?

let's consider the following scenario:

Model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  searchable do
    text :title
    integer :category_id, :references => Category
  end
end
```

Controller's method

```
def search
  @search = Article.search do
    keywords params[:q]
    with(:category_id, params[:c].to_i) if params[:c].present?
    facet :category_id
    data_accessor_for(Article).include = :category
    paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end
end
```

Haml view excerpt

```
- search.facet(:category_id).rows.each do |row|
  %li
    = link_to(row.instance.name, params.merge(:c => row.value).except(:page))
    %div.score= row.score
```

So I want to get total score of the facet that is a sum of scores of hits in this facet.

Comment: facing the same problem. Have you found any workaround?

Comment: @MarufRahman, after studying solr's source code I found that it does not provide this info. My workaround was to show the number of hits per facet as a measure of relevancy of the facet to search phrase. For the most important facet, I summed up scores of hits traversing them in code. This is always an option!